# readRDS(file) in R

Tags: r, crash, package

Whenever I try to install a package in R, I get the following error:

```
Error in readRDS(file) : unknown input format
```

This just started occurring after I had a system crash.  I am running 32 bit R 2.13.0 under windows 7.  I tried removing and re-installing R, but continue to get the error.  Is there any way I can fix this without deleting everything (i.e. all the packages I've installed) and starting over?

Thanks

Comment: I had installed R 3.4 and noticed that this error always occurs. Surprisingly, installing R 3.3 instead of 3.4 fixed the issue for me. 

(What could be the reason for this?)

Comment: @nikpod if you saved the file in 3.3 maybe you can't read it in 3.4

Answer (score 27, accepted):

These are suggestions I have come across:

1. Delete your `.Rhistory` and `.RData` files in the directory in which you are running R.
2. Run `update.packages()`
3. Try and detect "bad files" in your library directories. You can do this in R

   ```
   # List the library paths
   # The issue is likely to be in the first directory
   paths = .libPaths()

   ## Try and detect bad files
   list.files(paths, 
          pattern = "^00LOCK*|*\\.rds$|*\\.RDS$",
          full.names = TRUE)

   ## List files of size 0
   l = list.files(paths, full.names = TRUE)
   l[sapply(l, file.size) == 0]
   ```

   Delete any files/directories highlighted. You could use `file.remove()` if you really wanted to.
4. Delete the directory in which you have stored your downloaded packages.

Only solution 3 worked for me.

Ref:

- [R-sig-Debian mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-debian/2011-December/001740.html)
- Option 3 was a combination of answers provided by different people over the last few years, including Chunxiao Xu, Larry Hunsicker and Frank Harrell

Comment: same story. Had to switch for another directory

Comment: I have tried all the above solutions and none of them seem to work. I couldn't find the .Rhistory and Rdata files.

Comment: @amc Agreed. I've created a simple R solution to try and detect bad files/directories

Comment: Yeah for me it had to do with 1 offending library that had an rds file within it that was built by a newer R. I manually tried deleting dozens of libraries before finding the one. I wish I had found this solution first!

Comment: I run the code in solution 3, but it only returns the paths in the directory, i.e. https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLxdw.png. Could you please explain how to use `file.remove()` to automatically remove file with size 0?

Comment: Another solution that worked for me is that I changed it from .rds to a .RData file and read in the collection of workspace objects

Answer (score 7):

Run `find /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/ /usr/lib/R/library/ /usr/lib/R/site-library/ ~/.local/lib/ -iname '*rds' -a -size 0` and then delete the files found.

Comment: This did the trick (without needing to delete the entire package directory). I also had to delete a package lock file (`/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/00LOCK-pkg`). After deleting the files I reinstalled the affected packages.

Comment: I love you. This worked for me and I was not enjoying having to wrangle with R in order to fix R.

Answer (score 5):

Chunxiao Xu and Rando Hinn's solution above worked for me, with a minor tweak.

First, change directories to your personal R package directory, then run:  find -iname '*rds' -a -size 0

Delete the directories containing any 0 length files in the above list.  Then reopen R (or RStudio) and reinstall the deleted packages.

You should now be able to list the packages again.

Chunxiao Xu's original suggestion above lists ALL of the R package directories.  But the exact locations of these directories will vary from installation to installation, and their addresses will have to be edited for your installation.

Larry Hunsicker

Answer (score 3):

Something simple to try: if it is an .rda file use `load` instead of `readRDS`. You can then save the loaded file as an .rds and try `readRDS` again.

Comment: Related to this. I fixed it by downloading again the file in question from internet. Seems there was a small corruption and the error came up

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I had to do to solve this error:

- Open your Rstudio, go to install tab under packages
- Note your install to library path.(where your package will be saved)
- Go to the install library path.And hard delete the recent packages
- Refresh you package details in Rstudio

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me after I had to reboot my machine in the middle of installing several R packages.  I removed the latest installed packages by physically removing the files in the appropriate library directory, reinstalled them, and all was well.  I also had to remove a `00LOCK` directory in the library directory.

Answer (score 0):

You might have some problem with R packages .
See if the problem has occurred after you installed some packed or did you copied the packages.

What you can do is Copy all the packages from Library and save it somewhere, then Copy some packages on the Library and restart the R test it and see how it works you have to try with all the packages one by one .
I has the same issue and it was due to package problem.

Answer (score 0):

I checked for this issue on several forums and then I tried this and it worked for me:

1) Remove the ggplot2 package first

```
remove.packages("ggplot2")
```

2) Then Install the package again

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
```

3) restart rstudio and install your package again, hope this helps

Seems that the issue was with the required package (ggplot2 in my case) got corrupt and was hampering the installation of any new dependent package.

Answer (score 0):

I also had several problems opening an .RDS file, either "error reading from connection" or "unknown input format". I tried with several R versions, with version 3.4.2. the following worked:
(I accidentally uninstalled rstudio and installed it again, also installed older R version 3.4.2, I don't know if that changes anything)

1. set up a new working directory
2. I opened the RDS file directly instead of downloading it (so only saved to temp files), then I was able to open it in R
3. I moved it from temp files to my new working directory and used the `Data_Essay_Account <- readRDS("C:/.../newdirectory/Data_Essay_Account.RDS")` command and it worked.

Somehow properly downloading it and then moving it did not work, only after I had it in the temp files. Hard deleting packages did not work for me as I tried that initially.

Comment: Please use formatting tools to properly edit and format your question/answer.
Codes within sentences are to be formatted as `code` 
Very Important words to be **bold** , lesser important onces *Italic*
Also use lists if necessary

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the top few answers here, my issue was resolved not by doing anything with my installation of RStudio or cleaning local files, but by re-writing the `RDS` file.

I could confirm this because the file was stored in the cloud, and reading it from a variety of windows and mac laptops all failed, but similar `RDS` files from the same S3 bucket worked without a problem.

When I re-wrote the `RDS` file, the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as the OP, but in my case the problem .rds files were not 0 bytes but had file size >0 and were full of `NULL` characters (at least that's what I saw when I opened them in Notepad++)

By using `debugonce(loadNamespace)` before loading the library that was giving me the error (in my example it was the `VIM` package) I eventually traced my problem to corrupted .rds files in the META folder of the `forcats` package, which was installed as a 5th generation import when I installed `VIM`

```
    (In the rstudio environment pane)
 __NamesSpacesLoading__    chr[1:5] "forcats" "haven" "rio" "car" "VIM"
```

I then fixed by `VIM` problem simply by removing and reinstalling `forcats`
Adapting the code in @csgillespie accepted answer, I could have found this by trying to read all the rds files as below

```
paths = .libPaths()

l <- list.files(paths, 
           pattern = "*\\.rds$",
           ignore.case = T,
           recursive = T,
           full.names = TRUE)

checkRDS <- function(file) {
  tryCatch({
    readRDS(file)
    "OK"
  },
  error = function(cond) {
    return("Error")
  })
} 

l[sapply(l,checkRDS)=="Error"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by using `.libPaths()` and finding the 4.1 folder (my version of R was 4.1, so may differ). From there I closed R studio and deleted all the folders for each package.

I reinstalled all packages and found the packages which wouldn't download through the error messages. When I located the packages that didn't download I installed them by using: `install.packages("package", type = "binary")`.

A bit long but solved all my issues.

Answer (score 0):

My mirror was misconfigured. My mirror is Oregon State University because that is what I am closest too. [Here is a list of mirrors](https://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html). Call this code before installing any packages. More information in ?options.

```
mirror <- "https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/cran/"
local({
  r <- getOption("repos")
  r["CRAN"] <- mirror
  options(repos = r)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**The workaround**

Execute this command in the R console:

```
options(pkgType = "source")
```

You're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I was saved the RDS object with the `save()` function and not the `saveRDS()` function.

```
# Doesn't work
a = 1
save(a, file="test.rds") 
b = readRDS("test.rds")
print(b)
```

```
# Works
a = 1
saveRDS(a, file="test.rds") 
b = readRDS("test.rds")
print(b)
```