# readRDS fails to read in file in R. Is there an alternative?

Tags: r, readfile

I'm trying to read the RDS file I downloaded from here:

https://github.com/jcheng5/googleCharts/tree/master/inst/examples/bubble

However, when I try to load it into RStudio via:

```
data<- readRDS('/Users/nathanf/shinyCharts/healthexp.rds')
```

I get the Error: unknown input format.

I've searched and found a possible solution already posted on StackOverflow, but the solutions mentioned in it do not work.

Does not work:
[readRDS(file) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473831/readrdsfile-in-r)

Please note, I'm trying to do this with a freshly installed copy of R (3.2.1) on a Mac running Yosemite.

I've found articles online that say the readRDS function is now defunct. https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/base-defunct.html

Sooooooo....dearest community, what should I do?  Is there another way to read RDS files using a new function?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you, 
Nathan

Comment: Works for me. Also `readRDS()` is *not* defunct. What is defunct is `.readRDS()` (note the `.` in the function name)

Comment: The file seems to be "healthexp.Rds", not "healthexp.rds". Have you just not got the upper case right? Are you sure you've downloaded the raw .Rds file and not the github page for it? Did you clone the github repo?

Comment: how did you download it?  If you just click on "copy link to file" (or some such), you get an HTML file, not a raw binary download.  You may need to click through and View raw/Save to file (this echoes @Spacedman's third sentence above).  As for case-sensitivity: looks like OP is on MacOS, with case-insensitive file system ...

Comment: I was bogged down by a typo. Oops. Thanks for your help. --NF

Answer (score 4):

I faced exactly the same problem and I can recommend switching from .rds objects into .RData objects. Simply:

```
save(random_forest1, "random_forest2.RData")
```

and then

```
load("random_forest2.RData")
```

Just for clarity, you will find your object named as random_forest1 after using load function

Comment: I faced the same issue and solved by this answer when working with a large dataset (5.5GB). Not sure why this gets downvoted. (I upvoted it and it changed from "-2" to "-1"). 

`save(a_large_data.frame, file="datasaved.rds")` and then `readRDS(file="datasaved.rds")` gives me "unknown input format". But `load("datasaved.rds")` works.

Comment: That is funny, `load(*.rds)` also works here