# There is no such file or directory error, despite naming the file correctly and having correct directory

Tags: r, r-markdown

---

### output:
pdf_document: default
html_document: default

install.packages('tinytex')
tinytex::install_tinytex()

## Mid-term Assignment

##### Task 1 MODELING BINARY CHOICES

**1. Explore the data**

- Firstly, we check the first six rows in the dataset

```
skincare_data <- readRDS("skincare_data.RDS")
head(skincare_data)
```

**And the error I got**:

> skincare_data <- readRDS("skincare_data.RDS")
> Warning in gzfile(file, "rb") :
> cannot open compressed file 'skincare_data.RDS', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
> Error in gzfile(file, "rb") : cannot open the connection

Comment: try using `skincare_data <- readRDS("skincare_data.rds")` else refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31060420/readrds-fails-to-read-in-file-in-r-is-there-an-alternative

Comment: `getwd()` will tell you the current working directory - is this the same folder as the file is in? if not, change it with `setwd()`