# Installing R Packages Error in readRDS(file) : error reading from connection

Tags: r, package, ubuntu-14.04

Whenever I try to install any package in R on Ubuntu 14.04, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error in readRDS(file) : error reading from connection
```

I already tried the methods given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17448816/707145) but could not solve the problem.

Comment: @Pascal the error is different and OP notes that the solution provided in the link didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Pascal my comment was meant more of a "ping" to get your attention in case you moved on.

Comment: Have you tried a different mirror? Is this in RStudio or base R?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy, e.g. in a corporation office or university?

Comment: You should: A) post the code that caused the error, B) post the output from `sessionInfo()`and c) answer all the outstanding question above.

Comment: Also report the output of `options("repos")`.

Answer (score 15):

I was facing the same error and I restarted R session, it worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

1- Install the latest version of R form the [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/wily/r-base-core_3.2.3-1wily1_amd64.deb)  and try to install a package.

2-  If it is possible check it with another user account.

3- Try to install the R package [locally](https://www.stat.osu.edu/computer-support/mathstatistics-packages/installing-r-libraries-locally-your-home-directory).

4- If there is an RDS file created by the old version of R you may have another sort of problem, this is the warning from R help:

> Warning
>
> These functions have provided a stable interface since R 2.4.0 (when
>   the storage of serialized objects was changed from character to raw
>   vectors). However, the serialization format may change in future
>   versions of R, so this interface should not be used for long-term
>   storage of R objects.
>
> On 32-bit platforms a raw vector is limited to 2^31 - 1 bytes, but R
>   objects can exceed this and their serializations will normally be
>   larger than the objects.

Ref: help(serialize)

Comment: Please let us know if the above comments worked or not.

Answer (score 7):

If you have one or more incorrectly installed packages (e.g. because you had to force-reboot during installation) you need to re-install this/these package(s). You can find them using this code:

```
library(purrr)

.libPaths() %>%
set_names() %>%
map(function(lib) {
    .packages(all.available = TRUE, lib.loc = lib) %>%
    keep(function(pkg) {
        f <- system.file('Meta', 'package.rds', package = pkg, lib.loc = lib)
        tryCatch({readRDS(f); FALSE}, error = function(e) TRUE)
    })
})
```

This will return a nested list containing the broken packages:

```
$`/home/yourname/R`
[1] "brokenpkg"

$`/usr/lib64/R/library`
character(0)

$`/usr/share/R/library`
character(0)
```

You might need to delete the directories `00LOCK-<pkgname>` that R created in the library location while trying to install the packages.

Comment: Deleting all my packages and then re-installing worked for me

Comment: This does not actually work; returns empty lists for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error on Windows 10 after installing R 3.4.0 from 3.3.1 (all 64-bit). It was resolved by manually installing an unrelated package from CRAN (I used **ggplot2**). No idea what the root cause was, but perhaps this will work for you as well.

Output from my code:

```
> library(pacman)
> p_load(plyr, XLConnect, ggplot2, stringr, magrittr, kirkegaard, lubridate, weights, psych, psychometric, polycor, effsize, readr)
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Emil/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Error in install.packages : error reading from connection
 Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘BiocInstaller’
```

Then I restarted R, and ran the same code:

```
> library(pacman)
> p_load(plyr, XLConnect, ggplot2, stringr, magrittr, kirkegaard, lubridate, weights, psych, psychometric, polycor, effsize, readr)
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Emil/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Error in readRDS(dest) : error reading from connection
```

I.e. same code, different error. Odd. Then I restarted R again and installed a random package, then reran my code and it worked.

```
> install.packages("ggplot2")
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib/PACKAGES.rds': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Emil/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/PACKAGES.rds': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/ggplot2_2.2.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2782171 bytes (2.7 MB)
downloaded 2.7 MB

package ‘ggplot2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Emil\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpCq4cFX\downloaded_packages
> library(pacman)
> p_load(plyr, XLConnect, ggplot2, stringr, magrittr, kirkegaard, lubridate, weights, psych, psychometric, polycor, effsize, readr)
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Emil/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/effsize_0.7.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 36713 bytes (35 KB)
downloaded 35 KB

package ‘effsize’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Emil\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpCq4cFX\downloaded_packages

effsize installed
```

So, error seems to have had something to do with **pacman** trying to install **effsize**.

Comment: `It was resolved by manually installing an unrelated package from CRAN (I used ggplot2)` worked for me too. Odd... Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the **CRAN mirror** specified in `~/.Rprofile` was not reachable (I tested the link in a browser). So I used another [CRAN mirror](https://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html)

**Quick Fix**:

```
update.packages(ask = FALSE, repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
```

**Permanent Solution:**

```
echo "options(repos=c(CRAN='http://cran.us.r-project.org')) # backup if default is unreachable" >> ~/.Rprofile
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem.
I followed the instructions given here
http://www.ryantmoore.org/files/ht/htrtargz.pdf
and installed all the required dependencies separately as and when they were required.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting error running `install.packages("mice")`

1. I tried everything suggested by user1436187.
2. After this I tried running update.packages(). received same error. I also got an error message where it was unable to run some command due to permissions.
3. I closed my current session of R and restarted it again as an administrator.
4. Ran command which was giving error earlier `install.packages("mice")`

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error when i installed most recent version of R. many a times most recent version is not stable( for me, it was 3.4.2 on 08/11/2017). I uninstalled it and installed 3.4.1( earlier stable version), now there is no issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem:

```
readRDS(file) : error reading from connection.I did follow:
```

I found `file.rds` in folder `Downloads`, then made copy of file and put in another folder. And then I chose directory in:

```
R Session->Set working Directory->Choose directory->my new folder
```

After this action it works

And one interesting thing. When I copied the file downloaded by the function download.file("http://..../file.rds", "file.rds") and put the file in folder-directory, the problem remained. But when I copied the link http://....../file.rds and pasted it into the address bar, the file was downloaded in the folder Downloads on my computer from which I copied it and moved to the directory -folder. So I did not download file by the function of R download.file, copied file from Downloads and put it in the folder-directory. In this case, it works

Answer (score 0):

Hit the same error related to readRDS when I went to load "tidyverse". I had been working with VS Code in R. Maybe something glitched.

Solution that worked for me. **Update all package**s, it was a big list. and I had to reinstall some individually again following the error outputs.

Error in readRDS(file) : error reading from connection #went away and tidiverse loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, tried the solutions above. None worked for me. So I tried a different thing

### Diagnostic

When that happens, the problem lies somewhere else. There's some corrupt file, might be the package DB, might simply be some other corrupt file in some downstream dependency; problem is, I haven't found a way to pinpoint if it is one or the other, which one has the issue, or, for that matter, to specifically fix that file and be done with; once the offending downstream dependency is fixed (if that's the case) it might be as easy as uninstall that package and install it all over again (or let the dependency manager do its work), but unfortunately I couldn't find it.

### Solution

Delete `~/R`, or if you want to be on the safe side, move it to some other directory (like `~/R-backup`); then reinstall whatever you might need specifically for the problem you're having. Even RStudio will prompt you, when it finds some library, to make it for you.

This is admittedly a bit harsh, and it might take a while until you get everything installed properly. It might even fail if you jury-rigged, or hot-fixed some module; in that case, *do* keep the backup, just in case. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to pinpoint the offending file or downstream dependency, and (in my case) I couldn't keep working without `dplyr` and `ggplot2`

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are saving the `rds` file in correct format :

```
saveRDS(model, "path/file.rds")
```

Then read the `.rds` file using

```
model <- readRDS("path/file.rds")
```