# Can't install any package ( Error in readRDS(dest) : error reading from connection )

Tags: r, installation, package

For a week I've been trying to install packages, but an error message keeps occuring : Error in readRDS(dest) : error reading from connection.

I had never seen this message before and I haven't done any update in-between.

Here is what I do :

- I open R version 3.4.4 (but I've tried with 3.4.2 and 3.4.3 too)
- I click on packages -> install packages
- I choose a mirror (France Paris 2, but I've tried many others)
- I choose a package (I wanted to install foreach, but I have the same message with any package)
- Then I have this message "Error in readRDS(dest) : error reading from connection"
- If I click again on packages -> install packages, I instantly have the same message "Error in readRDS(dest) : error reading from connection"

I run R as administrator. I've tried uninstalling /re-installing R, with different versions (from 3.4.2 to 3.4.4). Note that I work in an office, on a server, but my colleagues doesn't have any problem installing packages.

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473831/readrdsfile-in-r

Comment: That's not the same error message, and the 3 solutions he offered did not worked for me.
However, as mentionned by someone in this post, switching to a much older version of R (3.3.2) worked for me. Still it would be great to use 3.4.

Comment: Yep, I would agree.  I know in the past when I've had package-related issues with R version updates, i've had to update each of my packages with `update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE)`

Comment: Try this https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203864278-Error-in-readRDS-pfile-error-reading-from-connection-when-updating-loading-installing-packages

Comment: And this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31935516/installing-r-packages-error-in-readrdsfile-error-reading-from-connection

Comment: @Tung I haven't tried yet the solution offered in the first link (support.rstudio), I will if I have to switch back to 3.4. In the meantime, I'll stick to version 3.3. Thx for your answer.