# Installing Bioconductor packages error --> Error in readRDS(dest) : error reading from connection

Tags: r, package, bioconductor

I have been trying to install Bioconductor in R (version 4.0.5). Each time I try to insert the following code, I get some error like:

```
>if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
  install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install(version = "3.12")

'getOption("repos")' replaces Bioconductor standard repositories, see
'?repositories' for details

replacement repositories:
    CRAN: http://cran.csiro.au/

Bioconductor version 3.12 (BiocManager 1.30.13), R 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)
Installing package(s) 'BiocVersion'
Error in readRDS(dest) : error reading from connection
```

I have already tried the previous solutions given by others [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473831/readrdsfile-in-r) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31935516/installing-r-packages-error-in-readrdsfile-error-reading-from-connection/55997765). I also restarted it again as an administrator. But nothing is working.

I can easily install the cran packages using the 'install.package()' command. I can also install packages using the tar.gz file; however, when I try to install Bioconductor packages, this problem is occurring. Also, it's not convenient to install packages using the tar.gz file as there are lots of dependent packages in Bioconductor. Everything was fine until yesterday, then suddenly my R crashed and I couldn't open R. So I decided to reinstall it. After that, this problem is occurring. Any sort of help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem for BioConductor packages. I found a working solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67453639/5341912).

```
install.packages("devtools")    
devtools::install_github("Bioconductor/BiocManager", ref="ghost-binary-repo")
```