# error after installing ggmap in r

Tags: r

I installed package `ggmap`. But when I wanted to use it , I got following error:

```
library(ggmap)
loading required package ggplot2
Error in readRDS(nsINFoFilePath) : unknown input format
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'ggmap'
```

I also uninstalled it using utils and reinstalled but same error appears again.

Comment: Did you restart R after installing ?

Comment: how about posting the output from your sessionInfo()

Comment: If restarting R doesn't work, you may want to check out the following [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473831/readrdsfile-in-r).  I don't know for sure this issue has the same cause but it is something to consider.

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling `ggplot2` first:

```
uninstall.packages("ggplot2")
```

and then installing both `ggplot2` and `ggmap`.