# R error: Namespace load failed for in readRDS(nsInfoFilePath)

Tags: r, cran

I am getting the following error when installing packages.

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ** in readRDS(nsInfoFilePath):

I have tried the reccomendations suggested here: [readRDS(file) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473831/readrdsfile-in-r)

I am running R on a high performance computing cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you are not exceeding the disk space quota on your userspace. You can check your quota using `quota -u [USERNAME]`.