# R Package Error(s)

Tags: r, install.packages

I'm running into a bunch of errors when trying to install any packages on R 3.4.4 on Windows 7. Originally, `installed.packages()` wasn't even working. I had to create the temp directory manually that it was trying to access. I've previously installed/uninstalled R on my machine before, so I'm guessing some of these problems might be stemming from that. I can now view my installed packages.

If I try something as simple as `install.packages("tidyverse")`, I'll get the following:

> `Installing package into
>   ‘C:/Users/areynolds/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’ 
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified) 
>   Error in readRDS(dest) : unknown input format`

Attempting `update.packages()` yields the same error. I've deleted my .Rhistory which saves to my Documents folder. My .libPaths() is the following:

> `[1] "C:/Users/areynolds/Documents/R/win-library/3.4"
>   [2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.4/library"`

I'm not really sure what else to try. I've been looking everywhere for the same problem but it's always a little different. I've tried specifying arguments to install.packages like dependencies = TRUE or lib = *path*. I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the steps outlined in the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473831/readrdsfile-in-r)?

Comment: @DeepakRajendran I've done all of them except deleting the directory where my packages are stored. I deleted the directory listed at [1] above. The second directory has ALL my packages there, including base. Should I still delete it?

Comment: @DeepakRajendran I gave up and uninstalled and reinstalled R. Works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error.

**Closing RStudio completely, then reopening it worked for me**.

Note: simply restarting the R Session (e.g. `.rs.restartR()`) *did not* work - I am not sure why