# can't install package in Rstudio

Tags: r

I tried to install ggtern, Ternary and Rtools (the latter as a test) but it doesn't work and always give me this error message

```
Error in readRDS(file) : unknown input format
Error in readRDS(pfile) : unknown input format
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this?
Thanks

Comment: Rtools is not an R package. It's a system package.

Comment: Have you tried the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473831/readrdsfile-in-r)?

Answer (score -1):

Which version of R you are using to install the package?

Possible solutions

1. Delete your .Rhistory and .RData files in the directory in which you are running R.
2. Run update.packages()
3. Try and detect "bad files" in your library directories. You can do this in R
4. Delete the directory in which you have stored your downloaded packages.