# Error in running a file in a specific folder, while the same file runs smoothly in other folders

Tags: r, compiler-errors, package, global

I am running the same `R` file (`file.R`) in 12 folders simultaneously (`m1, m2,... m12`) using a supercomputer. The file has exactly the same name and content, the only difference is that it is contained in different folders. There's no `.RData` file in any of each folder. All the files call the same `.RData` file in another folder. Similarly for the `R packages`.

The file runs smoothly in all folders but in folder `m2`, where the output of the `.Rout` file is:

```
Error in load(name, envir = .GlobalEnv) : 
  ReadItem: unknown type 0, perhaps written by later version of R
Calls: sys.load.image -> load
Execution halted
```

The file starts by:

```
##############################################################################
##                                                                          ##
##                              -  -  -  -  -  -                            ##
##                                                                          ##
##                           S I M U L A T I O N S                          ##
############################################################################## 
require(tidyverse)
require(dplyr)
require(scales)
require(pracma)
require(foreach)
require(doSNOW)
```

and the `.Rout` file does not even print the comments and packages. It exits immediately with that error message. I don't understand why folder `m2` is so exceptional. Any idea on this error?

PS: I'm sorry, I know I'm not giving you a replicable example, but I just can't replicate it. Running `bsub -n 2 -q long_int -Ip -W 48:00 -R "rusage[mem=20000]" -M 20000 -hl R CMD BATCH simulation_doParallel2.R` works fine.

Comment: There's a lot of information missing... Is there a `.RData` (yes, that's the full name) inside `m2`? Does it help to add `--vanilla` to R's options? Does it work if you rename `m2` to something else? Does it work if you symlink (or even copy, but I understand that kind of defeats the purpose) your `.RData` into each folder?

Comment: No there is no data file in `m2`. The script calls data in another folder. I haven't tried the `--vanilla` option. Yes, it works with another name.

Comment: There is a call to `sys.load.image` being triggered before anything else is run, and this suggests that there is something inside `m2` that is being automatically loaded during R's [startup sequence](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html)... An `.RData` file (usually hidden) would be the most likely culprit.

Comment: I see, but there are only other .R file or .Rout files in the folder.

Comment: @Andrew I know I'm beating a dead horse here a little, but just to be 100% sure, have you checked the hidden files? As you say this is a "supercomputer" I'll assume you're on Linux, so this would be accomplished in a terminal via `ls -a` (assuming your current terminal working directory was `m2`)

Comment: Maybe there are lock or empty files? [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17448816/5793905).

Comment: Yes there was an `.RData` hidden in the folder. Thank you @Andrew. I should give you the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think there might be an .RData on the folder where you call Rscript from... may be home

run: `find /home -iname *.RData` to find the file