# Download rds file from github repository

Tags: r, curl, github

I'm trying to download an rds file from github to practice some analysis but strugging to get it to work, I always get 'unknown input format'. I've read a few SO threads on it and this code should work but doesnt. Does anyone know where I might be going wrong?

```
 githubURL <- ("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lichenyangalexa/DataCamp-R-Project/raw/master/The%20Impact%20of%20Climate%20Change%20on%20Birds/Datasets/climate_raster.rds")
download.file(githubURL,"climate_raster.rds", method="curl")
climate <- readRDS("climate_raster.rds")
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If it can help you have a look [readRDS(file) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473831/readrdsfile-in-r)

Comment: Your Github link is incorrect for me at least, so the .rds file is just 1kb and blank, hence the error, it isn't actually an RDS file, just a file with a single line `404: Not Found`.

Comment: @caldwellst okay, do you know whats wrong with it? I'm totally new to this sort of thing! Thanks

Comment: @caldwellst ah okay thats a bummer I was really hoping to get a hold of that data!

Comment: @MeganCritchley Have a look through lichenyangalexa's Github, and find the data again to try and get a correct link if possible.

Comment: that the link i was using and copying the url from the download button https://github.com/lichenyangalexa/DataCamp-R-Project/blob/master/The%20Impact%20of%20Climate%20Change%20on%20Birds/Datasets/climate_raster.rds @caldwellst

Comment: Why don't you save the file to local disk and load it from there, if debugging net download is not your primary concern?