# Issues with readRDS - unknown input format

Tags: r

I have saved an R object (just a character vector) as an RDS on my mac. And synched it using git onto an Ubuntu machine.

When I am trying to read that RDS on the Ubuntu Machine, I get this error:

```
Error in readRDS(<file Name>) :
  unknown input format
```

Now, on both the machines I am using R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12) -- "Dark and Stormy Night"

I have done the same workflow multiple times in the past, and the serialized RDS ported just fine across platforms. hence, I do not think it is an OS related quirk. I have never experienced such an issue before.

Any help would be appreciated.

PS: Code used is simple `saveRDS()` and `readRDS()`.

The sad part is, same object when serialized a second time and carried thru, will be read fine on the Linux box.

Is there a more dependable process?

Comment: Maybe related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6473831/680068